# get variable name and its value in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perl script which now become very large.
I just wanna print all the variable name with their corresponding values
for e.g my script

```
$filename = "vivek.html";
$name = "$0";
$lang = "perl";
($dynamic_var) = $filecontent =~ /([\w\=\-\ ]+)(?=<)/;
```

and also some variable are initialized at run time.
output required :

```
$filename==>vivek.html
$name==>script.pl
$lang==>perl
$dynamic_var==>dynamic value
```

Comment: Declare all your variables as a hash element, the print each key/value pair.

Comment: but i dont know how many variable is used in the script.for declaring all variable as hash element i have to search each variable name..so it difficult

Comment: Why search each variable name while you could simply do `foreach (keys %vars)` and get them all? Besides this, getting all variables depends on their type and scope (lexical, global/package, etc). In the best case you'll have to dive into symbol tables and low-level processing. And do you have only (global) scalars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from good practice (you should use your own hash), but you can look at `%main::` hash which has stored all package (global) variables and as it seems you're using them exclusively,

```
my %vars;
BEGIN {
  @vars{keys %main::} = ();
}

# begin of your script
$filename = "vivek.html";
$name = "$0";
$lang = "perl";
# end of your script

print "\$$_==>$$_\n" 
  for sort grep { !exists $vars{$_} } keys %main::;
```